# Configuring Jenkins Cloud EC2 to fallback from one instance size to another

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2

I have configured Jenkins with EC2 Spot instances as executors. This works fine most of the time but sometimes there's not enough capacity and I don't want to pay on-demand prices but I do have a list of instance types, sizes and regions where I'm happy to run the work. I'd like to configure Jenkins to attempt to start one instance then if it fails, start a different one.

I've tried configuring multiple clouds but as soon as a job runs with the node label, all of the clouds start spot instances which is not the behaviour I want.

Ideally I'd like to specify 3 instance types and 3 regions for a total of 9 possible combinations and have it pick the cheapest but even just trying one after another would be fine.